# How to display a GeoTIFF raster in GeoGraphics?

Tags: polygons, geographics

I have a GeoTIFF raster file which I would like to display superimposed on a map in GeoGraphics and combine it with other GeoListPlot graphics.

Since I know the corners of the GeoTIFF raster, I am trying to use

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["Image",img],Polygon[...]}]
```

or

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["GeoImage",img],Polygon[...]}],
```

where the Polygon is defined by the location of the corners of the image. However, the following command does not work (img is the raster image):

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", img}], 
  Polygon[GeoPosition /@ {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}]}]
```

But replacing the Polygon with GeoDisk works:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", img}], 
  GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], 1000000]}]
```

and also replacing the image with just a color square works:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[LightBlue], 
  Polygon[GeoPosition /@ {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}]}]
```

Here's a minimal version of the code that reads a GeoTIFF image and displays it on in the square given by the coordinates {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}:

```
img = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hbzcqwqpmihite/Napoleonstein20160702-COLOR.tif?dl=0", "GeoTIFF", "DownSamplingFactor" -> 16];
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", img}],Polygon[GeoPosition[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}]]}]
```

But if the corner points are given as GeoPositions, the GeoGraphics statement does not work:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", img}],Polygon[GeoPosition/@{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}]}]
```

Comment: Your file is unavailable. Please fix the link. Note that https://imgur.com/ accepts TIFF format.

Comment: Link should work now again.

Comment: Thanks. The link now works, but the code `Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hbz...` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to write

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"Image", img}],
Polygon[GeoPosition[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}]]}]
```

For some strange reason mapping GeoPosition on each of the corners inside the call to Polygon does not work.

Comment: Thanks, this answers also another related problem in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151931/19960)