# How to apply GeoStylingImageFunction to graphics primitives in GeoGraphics?

Tags: image-processing, geographics

From the [`GeoStylingImageFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoStylingImageFunction.html) documentation you can apply different functions to the background and to geographic areas.

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["StreetMap", GeoStylingImageFunction -> Sharpen], EdgeForm[Black], 
  GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{40.7148, -73.9948}], Quantity[250, "Meters"]]}, 
 GeoBackground -> 
  GeoStyling["StreetMap", GeoStylingImageFunction -> (Blur[#1, 10] & )]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I need to do the same but with graphics primitives.  The issue I am having is that primitives are not drawn with the specified `GeoStyling`.  Instead they are drawn with default `Graphics` directives (i.e. Black).

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["StreetMap", GeoStylingImageFunction -> Sharpen], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Rectangle[GeoPosition[{40.7126, -73.9977}], GeoPosition[{40.7171, -73.9918}]]}, 
 GeoBackground -> 
  GeoStyling["StreetMap", GeoStylingImageFunction -> (Blur[#1, 10] & )]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I was hoping to see is a rectangle with the sharpened image of the map within it; as is seen with the circle.

I have several locations to mark and I can use a `Rectangle` for all of them if that makes it easier.  `locs` can be used as a sample of locations to try the solution.

```
SeedRandom[4297];
locs = GeoPosition /@ 
  Reverse[RandomPoint[
    DiscretizeGraphics[
     EntityClass["Neighborhood", "DowntownNeighborhoods::NewYork::NewYork::UnitedStates"][
      "Polygon"]], 
         5], {2}]
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found two ways:

**1. GeoBoundsRegion**

In case you just want a rectangle, the easiest is:

```
mygeoreg = GeoBoundsRegion@GeoBounds@
GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{40.7148,-73.9948}],Quantity[250,"Meters"]]

GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["StreetMap",GeoStylingImageFunction->Sharpen],
EdgeForm[Black], mygeoreg},
GeoBackground->GeoStyling["StreetMap",GeoStylingImageFunction->(Blur[#1,10]&)]]
```

[image]

**2. Polygon**

In case you want any geometric region (not only a rectangle), you can use `Polygon`... but there is a trick, or rather it seems to be a bug for which i found a workaround as described in [this related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134563/19960).
The "bug" is that `GeoStyling[anymapstyle ...]` do only work with an arbitrary `Polygon` if the coordinates are globally (and not individually) wrapped with `GeoPosition`.

For example:

```
mypoly={{40.71483703495285`,-73.99605494339924`},{40.716520051111`,-73.99470827199157`},{40.71476678743837`,-73.99434102007059`},{40.71491340888779`,-73.99277933338962`},{40.71343695345883`,-73.99386079093283`},{40.71406393970131`,-73.99485503905909`},{40.71289656406121`,-73.99692746298048`},{40.714563276515705`,-73.99552263170379`}};

GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["StreetMap",GeoStylingImageFunction->Sharpen],
EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@GeoPosition@mypoly},
GeoBackground->GeoStyling["StreetMap",GeoStylingImageFunction->(Blur[#1,10]&)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great find with both `GeoBondsRegion` and the special `Polygon` `GeoPosition` format. (+1) Will wait a bit just in case.